# Passing page title from Laravel 5.5 to Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, laravel

In my laravel controller I wrote:

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all(); // get all products
        $products['page_title'] = 'Demo Products'; //  page title

        return response()->json($products);
    }
```

And in Angular 4, I wrote for this:

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService, private title: Title) {  }
ngOnInit() {
    //console.log('data');

    this.productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.products = data;
        this.title.setTitle(data.page_title);
      },
```

And in the html under the angular I wrote the following:

```
<article class="col-md-4"  *ngFor="let product of products">
<div class="font-weight-bold">{{product.product_name}}</div>
<p>{{product.description}}</p>
<p>{{product.rating}}</p>
</article>
```

In index.html, I wrote `<title></title>`

It shows the console error as below:

---

> ProductComponent.html:7 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object
>   Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

In postman, I see the following:

```
    "18": {
        "id": 19,
        "product_name": "Adam Walsh",
        "description": "Rabbit coming to look for her, and the small ones choked and had just upset the week before. 'Oh, I BEG your pardon!' cried Alice in a shrill, loud voice, and see after some executions I have to ask.",
        "rating": 0,
        "price": 59.2,
        "created_at": "2018-03-22 11:04:39",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-22 11:04:39"
    },
    "19": {
        "id": 20,
        "product_name": "Marilyne Kulas II",
        "description": "I want to stay in here any longer!' She waited for a minute or two sobs choked his voice. 'Same as if his heart would break. She pitied him deeply. 'What is it?' he said, turning to Alice an.",
        "rating": 5,
        "price": 13.5,
        "created_at": "2018-03-22 11:04:39",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-22 11:04:39"
    },
    "page_title": "Demo Products"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is sent because *ngFor requires an array to iterate.

Assigning  $products['page_title'] as if $products was an associative array is wrong. $products is a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection. When sending it as json, Laravel parse it as an indexed array. But i guess you broke it by assigning 'page_title' this way.

Try to print_r($products) before sendind it, to check that.

I'd rather do something like this :

```
return response()->json(['data' => $products, 'page_title' => 'Demo Products']);
```

And in angular :

```
this.productService.getProducts()
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.products = response.data;
    this.title.setTitle(response.page_title);
  },
```